# OutputStream that directly writes my list of byte chunks

Tags: java, stream, outputstream

I have a library which generates a PDF document and writes it to an `OutputStream`. The `OutputStream` is passed to the PDF library. I need to store the resulting data in a <del>`List<Byte[]>`</del>`List<byte[]>` with each entry having a fixed length of 255 bytes. (I cannot change anything about this requirement, see more in the comments.)

Now the easiest solution would be to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and writing (and disassembling) the resulting byte array to the byte array list.

But I want a more efficient solution which requires less memory. I want the output stream to directly generate the byte array list.

My solution is to extend `OutputStream`, override `write()` and write the data directly into the `List<byte[]>`.

This requires some effort (e.g. track the amount of bytes already received) and therefore I wonder, if there is an easier solution using the other available `OutputStream` implementations.

E.g. I thought about utilizing `BufferedOutputStream` somehow, but I think that won't work. The basic idea was to implement another `OutputStream`, pass it to a `BufferedOutputStream` with 255 byte capacity and write a new chunk entry, every time `BufferdOutputStream` flushes its buffer when it's full. I think this doesn't work, because `BufferedOutputStream` doesn't use its buffer anymore if too much bytes are written at once (as far as I understood its source code).

Comment: Why not make `List<byte[]>`?

Comment: Define 'expects a list of 255 byte chunks'. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP A `List<Byte[]>` with each `Byte[]` entry having length 255. (The last entry can have less than 255 bytes). @Whatzs Yes I could use `byte[]` instead of `Byte[]` if the framework communicating with the target server didn't expect the latter.

Comment: Read your last paragraph again, then look back a the previous two (“My solution is to extend `OutputStream`, override `write()` and write the data directly into the `List<Byte[]>`. This requires some effort…” and then read your last paragraph again. I hope then you realize what great lengths your are going just to avoid the “some effort” of the straight-forward solution…

Comment: I think you're trying to say the solutions would nearly  require the same effort, as I also need to implement `OutputStream` in the second solution. But if my wrapped inner stream just needed to write 255 bytes into a list I think it would be less effort (`new BufferedOutputStream(new WriteChunkToListOutputStream(), 255`)

Comment: I don’t see any benefit in using (abusing) a `BufferedOutputStream` here. Trying to force a class to do something it is not intended for, is actually even *more complicated* than writing a solution using a base class that is designed for inheritance, i.e where you can be sure that no method will bypass your logic. But actually, I’d give the author of that framework a kick and refuse to implement anything based on an API that expects a `List<Byte[]>`. There is no backend-API that could process that efficiently, so there must be an expensive conversion back to `byte[]` on the framework side…

Comment: As you can see in my question I already came to the conclusion that BufferedOutputStream won't work. So I asked if there is something similar that will work. [ChunkedOutputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/ChunkedOutputStream.html) for instance looks promising, but it only works if the PDF writer doesn't call `write(int b)` - only `write(byte[], int, int)` method.

Comment: How are you proposing to *send* this `List<Byte[]>`? What protocol is the recipient expecting you to use?

Comment: The `List<Byte[]>` is required due to communication with a SAP backend. It's not the framework's fault. It maps tables as `List`s and wraps around SAP JCo which maps SAP `RAW` data type to Java `Byte[]`. At least I just found a hint on the web which says `Byte[]`. If that's a performance issue I just try `byte[]`. Didn't try it yet, since I didn't see a problem.

Comment: Well, a `Byte[]` takes four times the space (eight times on 64Bit JVM w/o compressed oops) of a `byte[]` and processing a `Byte[]` implies dealing with nullability, etc. But what’s more important, is the necessity of converting back and forth between these representations. But I’m quite confused by you statement that you made up the requirement of producing a `List<Byte[]>` by some “hint on the web” and that you could try something different. You should rethink you programming strategy, e.g. consider using actual API *specifications* as starting point…

Comment: Thanks for the information about `Byte`. Well, "hint on the web" was actually the [specification](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/de/47/13097544d921c2e10000000a114a6b/content.htm) + another source. The specs say `Byte ()` which isn't actually a real type. But I think we're leaving the topic here ;-)

Comment: You appear to be talking about a protocol for sending bytes over a socket. If so, Java types like `List<x>` are beside the point. Please clarify.

Comment: As I already said a few comments earlier: I'm using SAP JCo (SAP Java Connector), a proprietary library which means I operate on a higher level than sockets. I don't know how JCo sends the data internally. Also I clearly say I need a `List<Byte[]>` and I can pass a OutputStream to my PDF library and I try to find an efficient way for this. I really don't understand what's hard to understand here, EJP and bmargulies

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick implementation of what I proposed in my question. It's not tested, though. But I have to make some specific changes before using it in my code and thought I'd share it before applying those changes.

```
public class ByteArrayListGeneratingOutputStream extends OutputStream
{
   private byte[] buf;
   private int off = 0;
   private int size;
   private List<byte[]> result = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

   public ByteArrayListGeneratingOutputStream(int size)
   {
      this.size = size;
      buf = new byte[size];
   }

   public List<byte[]> getResult()
   {
      return result;
   }

   @Override
   public void write(int b) throws IOException
   {
      allocateBufferIfNeeded();
      buf[off++] = (byte) b;
      flushBufferIfNeeded();
   }

   @Override
   public void write(byte buf[], int off, int len) throws IOException
   {
      if ((off < 0) || (off > buf.length) || (len < 0) || ((off + len) > buf.length) || ((off + len) < 0))
      {
         throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
      }
      while (len > 0)
      {
         allocateBufferIfNeeded();
         int effectiveLen = Math.min(len, size - this.off);
         System.arraycopy(buf, off, this.buf, this.off, effectiveLen);
         this.off += effectiveLen;
         off += effectiveLen;
         len -= effectiveLen;
         flushBufferIfNeeded();
      }
   }

   private void flushBufferIfNeeded() throws IOException
   {
      if (off == size)
      {
         flush();
      }
   }

   private void allocateBufferIfNeeded()
   {
      if (buf == null)
      {
         buf = new byte[size];
         off = 0;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void flush() throws IOException
   {
      if (off > 0)
      {
         result.add(buf);
         off = 0;
         buf = null;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void close() throws IOException
   {
      flush();
   }
}
```